# Rails routes root with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource in my `routes.rb` like this:

```
map.resources :users, :only => [:index] do |user|
  user.resources :projects
end
```

which gives me URLs like `/users/2/projects`, which will show all projects owned by `user` 2. After a user is signed in, I'd like this to be the root page, using `map.root`. How would I set `map.root` to enable this? I'm using devise, so I can get the current user with `current_user`, but I'm not sure this is available in `routes.rb`.

Comment: What about setting the root page to be a redirector? And then having like `Site::home` redirect the user to that page? That way guests would not be affected.

Comment: @webdestroya - That could work. I don't have to worry about guests though; it's a private site so anyone not logged in is redirected to a login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're solving this with a HomepageController that renders two different templates based on `if current_user`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was expecting routes.rb to deal with things like this, but I suppose it makes sense to keep that kind of logic out of there. Sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You'd set up your route to a `RootController` controller in `routes.rb` alongside your existing nested route:

```
map.root :controller => :root
```

The controller `RootController`'s `index` action could then render the `index` action of the `ProjectsController`:

```
class RootController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :controller => :projects, :action => :index
  end
end
```

And, finally, `ProjectsController` would make use of `current_user` to render the appropriate list of projects:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all.find_by_user(current_user)
  end
end
```

This glosses over details of authentication etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to that page after authentication in your filter method:

```
redirect_to user_projects_path(logged_in_user)
```