# How can I redirect a user's home (root) path based on their role using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, devise, cancan

I'm working on a project management app, and in the app, I have **project_managers** and **clients**. I'm using Devise and CanCan for authentication/authorization.

At what point after login should I be redirecting the user to their own specific controller/layout/views? Is there a way to check for `current_user.role` in `routes.rb` and set the root (or redirect) based on whether or not they're a project manager or a client? Is this a change I can make in Devise somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any help!
--Mark

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799393/rails-routes-root-with-nested-resource - the answer there was to create a separate controller for the homepage that does the routing. You can't access that Devise information inside routes.rb.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your `routes.rb` file won't have any idea what role the user has, so you won't be able to use it to assign specific root routes.

What you can do is set up a controller (for example, `passthrough_controller.rb`) which in turn can read the role and redirect. Something like this:

```
# passthrough_controller.rb
class PassthroughController < ApplicationController
  def index
    path = case current_user.role
      when 'project_manager'
        some_path
      when 'client'
        some_other_path
      else
        # If you want to raise an exception or have a default root for users without roles
    end

    redirect_to path     
  end
end

# routes.rb
root :to => 'passthrough#index'
```

This way, all users will have one point of entry, which in turn redirects them to the appropriate controller/action depending on their role.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753871/how-can-i-redirect-a-users-home-root-path-based-on-their-role-using-devise/4754097#4754097 is a better implementation, as it does not create a new controller just for redirection. Also, this would result in 1 extra round trip from browser to server every time a user is redirected to root_path

Comment: Elegant solution that does not require to change any existing code, i.e. I can keep all `redirect_to root_path` statements as they were before. I like it :)

Comment: This works nicely for me. I decided to throw it in my application controller, and everything seems dandy... But is there any reason you set up a brand new controller for it? Just wondering if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: This controller can easy be bypass if the user enters directly another path in the url. :(

Answer (score 22):

The simplest solution is to use `lambda`:

```
root :to => 'project_managers#index', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.role == 'project_manager' }
root :to => 'clients#index'
```

Comment: It worked for me. I have a question though. I'm using Ruby 2.3.0 and it allows me to use new stabby lambda syntax. But I'm getting syntax error with `constraints: -> { ... }`. It works fine if I use `lambda` instead of `->`. Any idea about this?

Comment: It's supposed to be possible to use a proc/lambda for the `:to` option (`root to: proc { |env| ...}`), but I ran into various problems with that since it seems to break `url_for`.  This solution worked without breaking `url_for`.  +1!

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to pass a proc to the `authenticated` method like this (I'm using rolify in this example):

```
authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.has_role?(:manager) } do
  root to: "managers#index", as: :manager_root
end

authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.has_role?(:employee) } do
  root to: "employees#index", as: :employee_root
end

root to: "landing_page#index"
```

Note that in Rails 4 you *have* to specify a unique name for each root route, see [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393) for details.

Comment: let's vote up for this answer! should be accepted as correct

Comment: Is there a way to use the user in deciding the path? I.e. `root to: organization_path(user.organization)`

Answer (score 8):

I do this in a Rails 3 app that uses Warden. Since Devise is built on top of Warden, I think it'll work for you, but be sure to experiment with it a bit before relying on it.

```
class ProjectManagerChecker
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.env['warden'].user.role == 'project_manager'
  end
end

# routes.rb
get  '/' => 'project_managers#index', :constraints => ProjectManagerChecker
get  '/' => 'clients#index'
```

If the user's role is "project_manager" the ProjectManagersController will be used - if it's not the ClientsController will be used. If they're not logged in at all, `env['warden'].user` will be nil and you'll get an error, so you'll probably want to work around that, but this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually tried this one first, but I couldn't get it to work (probably because I'm new to this). Not to mention- I can barely figure out what I'm doing at this point, so the idea of "experimenting with it" is scary as hell!

Answer (score 3):

Blog post with the implementation http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role/