# How can I redirect root based upon role using Rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, device, cancan

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753922/1393002) to a similar question but in my case I'm using [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify).

The problem I'm running into is in `passthrough_controller.rb` where I can't access the Rolify `.has_role?` function:

```
class PassthroughController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      redirect_to 'restaurants#index'
    else
      redirect_to 'http://www.google.com'
    end
  end
end
```

I have logged in using a user that I know has an admin role but it still redirects me to my `else` clause.

I couldn't find anything on the [Rolify github](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) page on how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does current_user definitely work and not return null? Are you using Devise and CanCan?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `current_user` works because if I tried `current_user.role` I would get `NoMethodError in PassthroughController#index` with `undefined method 'role' for #< User:0x007fd0ddd3b070>` message. And yes, I'm using Devise and CanCan.

Comment: Did you generate the role model and follow all the steps on the readme?

Comment: Also try adding the role to the current user in the index to make sure that is working. current_user.add_role :admin

Comment: Yup. My Rolify stuff works perfectly throughout my website.

Comment: I did `current_user.add_role :admin` then the usual `if current_user.has_role? :admin ... ` but I got a `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` from my Chrome browser.

Comment: Hmm. See if your admin shows up with this: admins = Role.find_by_name('admin').users just print the list in a view.

Comment: I ran it in my Rails Console and got back the correct user info.

Comment: Im not sure :( the method could not be available because it needs to be included in ApplicationController is my only thought but I dont know how to include it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple.

I just needed to prefix my `restaurants#index` with a `/` so my code should've looked like this:

```
  def index
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      redirect_to '/restaurants#index'
    else
      redirect_to 'http://www.google.com'
    end
  end
```

I didn't have the prefix in the beginning because that's how I defined my root in my `routes.rb` (`root :to => 'restaurants#index'`)

Comment: You could also use [resource routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to improve your example.

Comment: This answer can be very misleading to beginners. What you do here is redirecting to '/restaurants' path with 'index' anchor. The syntax in routes.rb file is different from how one should access routes in the controllers. Please change the first redirect to restaurants_path and correct the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you could just use render to do this as opposed to uses either routes or redirects.

```
def index
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      render "admin" # where admin.html.erb is in the same folder as index.html.erb
    else
      # do nothing - render default view
    end
end
```