# How do I refactor this case statement to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

So what I would like to do is to do redirects based on the role of the `current_user`.

This is what I have:

```
  path = case current_user.roles.where(:name => "vendor")
    when :vendor
      dashboard_path
    when :guest
      home_path
    else
      home_path
  end

  redirect_to path
```

I am using `cancan` and the only way to figure out the role of a user, that I know of, is to either do `current_user.has_role? :admin` or `current_user.roles.where(:name => role_name)`.

Given those constraints (or tell me another way to figure out the role of a user) how do I get this case statement to work?

**Edit 1**

Assume that I am checking for multiple roles, not just the 2 I have here - could be 4 or 5.

**Edit 2**

To be clear, this is my current setup.

I am using Devise, CanCan & Rolify. Rolify allows a user to have multiple roles, but my application won't have that use case. A user will just have one role. They can either be a `vendor, buyer, guest, superadmin`.

If they are a `vendor`, they can only see the `dashboard_path` that belongs to them. They can't see any other `vendor storefront` that belongs to anyone else. They also should not be able to see products from other vendors. So, once they login, their `root_path` should be `dashboard_path` not `home_path` which is what every other role's `root_path` will be.

If they are a `guest`, they can see everything except the prices - I already have this logic working. I achieved this like this:

```
if user.has_role? :guest
    can :read, [Product, Vendor, Banner]
    cannot :view_prices, Product
end
```

Then in my view, I just did something like this:

```
<% if can? :view_prices, Product %>
    <div class="price pull-right">
      <%= number_to_currency(@product.price) %> ea
    </div>      
<% else %>
   <span class="no-price pull-right"><%= link_to "Log In To See Price", login_path %></span>
<% end %>
```

So, basically...my real goal is to try and change the `root_path` depending on the role the user has. I am basically trying to implement the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753871/how-can-i-redirect-a-users-home-root-path-based-on-their-role-using-devise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FINAL ANSWER** *(for earlier anwsers, see below)*

If your users can only have one role, I'd say *your current implementation is not exactly appropriate*. However, if you really need to keep this implementation, you can do something like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this will return the name of the first (so the only one) 
  # role that your user has, or nil. 
  def role_name
    roles.first.try( :name ) 
  end
end
```

so now your case statement would work :

```
path = case current_user.role_name
         when 'vendor' ; dashboard_path
         when 'guest'  ; home_path
         when 'foo'    ; bar_path
         else home_path
       end
```

I still encourage you to wrap your case statement in a helper for reusability and easier maintainance.

**EARLIER ANSWER**

I'm not sure i understand your question, but i think you don't need a case statement here :

```
redirect_to (current_user.has_role? :vendor ? dashboard_path : home_path)
```

another way is to push part of the responsability to the user class (or a presenter):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def home_page
    # here some logic to return a symbol like :home or :dashboard,
    # depending on your roles implementation. Your User could even use
    # a state machine to do this, or have multiple decorators.
  end
end
```

and then with a helper

```
 def home_path_for( user )
   case user.home_page
     when :home      ; home_path
     when :dashboard ; dashboard_path
     when :foo       ; bar_path
     else home_path
   end
 end
```

**FIRST EDIT**

if your user can have multiple roles at a time, i'd say a case statement is not appropriate. `case` is a branching statement that is appropriate when you only have **one and only one input** and **one and only one outcome** out of a set of possible outcomes.

So you have to reduce your list of roles to an intermediate state, for instance :

```
 DASHBOARD_ROLES = [:vendor, :admin]
 CLIENT_ROLES    = [:client, :prospect]
 BASIC_ROLES     = [:logged_visitor]

 if (DASHBOARD_ROLES & user_roles).any?
   :admin_dashboard
 else if (CLIENT_ROLES & user_roles).any?
   :client_dashboard
 # additionnal, different logic is possible
 else if (BASIC_ROLES & user_roles).any? && user_logged_in? && user_roles.first != :prospect
   :logged_dashboard
 else
   :home
 end
```

this is a completely different kind of logic.

Comment: Well....there are multiple roles - not just a `:vendor`. So I need more than just a ternary redirect. Re: your helper, I am doing effectively that with a controller - which is why I am using this case. Your case in the helper won't necessarily help me because I need to check for multiple roles.

Comment: what i did here is to split the responsibilities : the user class determines what kind of home page is attributed to a particular user, and then the controller (helper) routes to the correct path. So it would be the responsibility of a user to check his own roles. I'd say a __case statement would rapidly become a hassle to implement such logic__, that's why i'm talking about state machines or decorators ; I recommend that you read about design patterns (many good books out there) because there are many ways to solve such problem in a much more maintainable way that with a "case".

Comment: I will definitely look into design patterns. For this case, a user can only have 1 role - not multiple roles. But, there can be multiple roles (i.e. vendor, buyer, guest, admin, superadmin, etc.). No one will have multiple roles. Makes sense? I am still struggling with understanding your approach - specifically the `home_path_for(user)` - even with the case where a user can have only 1 role.

Comment: sorry, i assumed that your user could have multiple roles (`user.roles` tricked me into it). It all depends on your implementation - in this case i'd say implement a method like `user#role` that would return a symbol or string, and then you could use it with the case statement. Currently in your system, as i understand it, `user#roles` may return 0, 1 or many `Role` objects, which is not coherent with the idea of a user only having one role. Perhaps you could post details about your implementation of roles for further help.

Comment: i think @SrikanthVenugopalan also thought that your user could have multiple roles, that's why he suggested the `active_role` idea which is more or less the same concept than my `home_page` method : let the user class choose which role should be used to determine what home page to redirect to.

Comment: I added more details about my implementation so you can see what I am trying to do, what I have, and where I am getting inspiration for my approach :)

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that User-Role relation is many-many. And also that the number of roles could be dynamic (more roles being added later). Hence I suggested using a hash and avoid `if-else` or `switches`.

Comment: updated my answer. I still think your implementation is not really adapted to what you want to do.

Comment: Or put in hash: 

path_cases = {
         'vendor' => dashboard_path,
         'guest'  => home_path,
         'foo'  => bar_path     
}

then 

path = path_cases[curren_user.role_name] rescue home_path

Comment: why use rescue ? you can provide a default value returned by the hash if the key / value pair does not exist. see Hash#fetch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably need to address the case when user has multiple roles, if that is possible.

Assuming a user has one role (though we can add more conditions if need be) Can you consider a hash?

Something like -

```
path = {:vendor => dashboard_path, :guest => home_path} [current_user.active_role] || default_path
```

I have made some assumptions -

1. `current_user.active_role` could be the current role of the user based on which you can redirect the answer.
2. `default_path` is self explanatory.

Comment: This is a possibility, for sure. In theory a user can have multiple roles. So this `path` local variable would go in my method above, right?

Comment: I am struggling to see how this would work....how would this detect when a user has `x` role, to send them to the right path? It doesn't seem to do it, to me.

Comment: When a user has multiple role, there must be another parameter to choose which role to use for deciding the path? Either a role hierarchy, or user choosing his/her current role? This is the `active_role`.