# Check the cookies/session in the routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, authentication

I want to set the root depending on the cookie/session. If the user is loged in already I want to check on the cookie/session and render a different page accordingly as the root url.

I want to do something like this

```
if (cookie with userID) do
   root 'user/index'
else
   root 'welcome/index'
end
```

Is there a way I could access the ApplicationController or something similar so that I could check on everything?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a different approach here. For example, you can map root path always to same action and put all logic into that action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to welcome_path and return unless logged_in?
    ... # rest of your code here 
  end
end
```

NOTE: Assuming `logged_in?` is a method that loads current user from session or returns nil.

Probably it's a good idea to move this kind of logic into a `before_filter` (in Rails4 `before_action`):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login

  def index
  end

  private

  def require_login
    redirect_to welcome_path unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

If most of your application (controllers scope) depends on a logged user, move it to the `ApplicationController` (filter will run on each request). You can skip it using `skip_before_filter :require_login` in the particular cases without this requirement.

By the way, if you want to achieve it via your routes, you can play with `constraints` ([doc here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)). Example code:

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#index', constraints: lambda { |request| request.session['user_id'].present? }
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

More ideas in this question: [How can I redirect a user's home (root) path based on their role using Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753871/how-can-i-redirect-a-users-home-root-path-based-on-their-role-using-devise)

Comment: Would it be a good idea to put it directly into the ApplicationController so that it is called every time ?

Comment: If most of your application (controllers) depends on a logged user, yes it is! Then you can skip it with `skip_before_filter :require_login` for the particular cases.

Comment: You're welcome @ConstantinJacob. I just updated answer with more ideas. Remember, accept and upvote (if you think it appropriate) answers is useful for the community :)

Comment: I will. I'm still working on making the first solution work...kinda hard. But I don't want to use any gem. I want to do it myself!

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I can still load the a in theory restricted website :/

Comment: What is `logged_in?`supposed to be? I have a private method in the ApplicationController `@current_user ||= User.find.(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

Comment: Yes, it looks good. Typo here (try to remove `.`): `User.find(session[:user_id])`?

Comment: No. Doesn't work. I set the session userid to nil in a logout action and I also deleted the localhost cookie myself in my browser. It still renders a controller where I haven't added the `skip_before_filter`. So in theory it should redirect me to the root url?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you're destroying properly the session (you can use `reset_session` method). Btw, it's difficult without seeing the code man.

Comment: We could continue the conversation there. I just added some comments to the gist.