# Redirecting to different action based on role in cancancan rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, cancan

How do you redirect to some action with cancancan based on role? Suppose I want the client role to be redirected to some different controller action, and all other roles to the default action.

for example:

```
def index

end
```

Is also the root action and after signing in all users redirected to index action.

Note: I use devise with cancancan.

Comment: Check the role, and `redirect_to` to appropriate URL. What's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I redirect a user's home (root) path based on their role using Devise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753871/how-can-i-redirect-a-users-home-root-path-based-on-their-role-using-devise)

Comment: You can use Devise's `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` to redirect according to the roles.